# Audio won't run from jar, only if I launch from CommandLine

Tags: java, audio, jar

This is my first time posting here, so if I exclude something important please do not hesitate to tell me!

Anyway, to the problem: I have compiled a jar file with a `.wav` included.

1) It runs in eclipse and plays the sound as needed by using:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(WAV_URL);
```

2) The music works in the jar if I run it using the commandline to launch it.

3) It does NOT work when just double-clicking to launch it. This is the option I need help with. Obviously I cannot "debug" this, as when I run it through commandline I can see everything, but it works.

```
 InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(WAV_URL);
    URL url = getClass().getResource(WAV_FILE_NAME);
    //System.out.println((url == null? "null.... " : url.getPath()));
    if (is == null) {
        is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(WAV_URL_2);
    }
    AudioInputStream audioIn = (is != null ? AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is) : AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();
    long milli = clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000;
    System.out.println("Milli: " + milli);
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime < milli) {

    }
    running = false;
```

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Best Regards.

Comment: Could you show the code, please?

Comment: All of it, or which part of it would you like to see?